# XML feed Joomla

Tags: xml, joomla, feed, joomla-extensions

I want to show a XML feed in my joomla website but i dont have a clue how to do it is there a way to do it? I've been looking for a while but nothing works for me.

Some of the extentions need a XML file or RSS feed, maybe it's possible to change the XML to a Xml file or RSS feed?

The xml feed:
https://www.managementboek.nl/code/affiliates/feed.php?affiliate=150&sort=7d&num=10

Answer (score 0):

You could write a custom module to do what you want to do. You can use PHP to parse the XML and then display it quite easily via the module template.

Otherwise the only option I see is, as you say, to convert the XML file into a format that the Display Feed module can read (e.g. RSS/ATOM) etc.

Are you able to create a module?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of ideas.
One is that you could look at JFeed and see about writing JFeedParserXml ... then JFeed will hand all of the work besides the specific parsing you need.

THe other thing is there is a mysterious field called "external reference" in many components (it is on the standard list and you should have it anyway). What you do with that field is generally put a link to which an http request will be made and the results parse. Basically you could do that, just write the parsing right in your component.